# Spark 2.1 - Error While instantiating HiveSessionState

Tags: apache-spark

With a fresh install of Spark 2.1, I am getting an error when executing the pyspark command.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/shell.py", line 43, in <module>
spark = SparkSession.builder\
File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 179, in getOrCreate
session._jsparkSession.sessionState().conf().setConfString(key, value)
File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 79, in deco
raise IllegalArgumentException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: u"Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState':"
```

I have Hadoop and Hive on the same machine.  Hive is configured to use MySQL for the metastore.  I did not get this error with Spark 2.0.2.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the same problem. Some of the answers `sudo chmod -R 777  /tmp/hive/`, or to downgrade spark with hadoop to 2.6 didn't work for me. 
I realized that what caused this problem for me is that I was doing SQL queries using the sqlContext instead of using the sparkSession.

```
sparkSession =SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").appName("appName").config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "./spark-warehouse").getOrCreate()
sqlCtx.registerDataFrameAsTable(..)
df = sparkSession.sql("SELECT ...")
```

this perfectly works for me now.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer on the /tmp/hive directory permissions.  That seems to have done the trick!

Comment: This error can be caused by all the 3 possibilities you mentionned (/tmp/hive rights, Hadoop conf or old Spark 1.6 code). Thanks for mentionning all of them.

Comment: any other solution that is not chmod 777? It's never a good idea giving that type of perm to dir (security speaking)

Comment: @AlessioG my answer does not recommend this solution, because it didnt work for me, and I'm not sure it is the root cause of the problem in general.

Answer (score 17):

I was getting same error in windows environment and Below trick worked for me.

in `shell.py` the spark session is defined with `.enableHiveSupport()`

```
 spark = SparkSession.builder\
            .enableHiveSupport()\
            .getOrCreate()
```

Remove hive support and redefine spark session as below:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder\
        .getOrCreate()
```

you can find `shell.py` in your spark installation folder.
for me it's in `"C:\spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark"`

Hope this helps

Comment: worked for me on windows... need to run few locally before i push it to the spark server on main server. +1

Answer (score 4):

Spark 2.1.0 - When I run it with yarn client option - I don't see this issue, but yarn cluster mode gives "Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState':".

Still looking for answer.

Answer (score 3):

The issue for me was solved by disabling *HADOOP_CONF_DIR* environment variable. It was pointing to *hadoop configuration directory* and while starting `pyspark` shell, the variable caused *spark* to initiate hadoop cluster which wasn't initiated.

So if you have *HADOOP_CONF_DIR* variable enabled, then you have to start hadoop cluster started before using *spark* shells

Or you need to disable the variable.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the spark-hive jar.

For example, if you are running on Scala 2.11, with Spark 2.1, you can use this jar.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-hive_2.11/2.1.0

Answer (score 0):

I saw this error on a new (2018) Mac, which came with Java 10.  The fix was to set `JAVA_HOME` to Java 8:

`` export JAVA_HOME=`usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8` ``

Answer (score 0):

I too was struggling in cluster mode. Added hive-site.xml from sparkconf directory, if you have hdp cluster then it should be at /usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/conf. Its working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error trying to run pyspark and spark-shell when my HDFS wasn't started.

Answer (score 0):

I have removed   ".enableHiveSupport()\"  from shell.py file  and its working perfect

/*****Before********/
 spark = SparkSession.builder\
            .enableHiveSupport()\
            .getOrCreate()

/*****After********/

spark = SparkSession.builder\
        .getOrCreate()

/*************************/

Answer (score 0):

**Project location and file permissions would be issue.** I have observed this error happening inspite of changes to my pom file.Then i changed the directory of my project to user directory where i have full permissions, this solved my issue.