# Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState':"

Tags: hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

While printing the schema of a SQL database,I am getting the following error:

[image]

Comment: Hi, if you found the answer satisfactory, please kindly appreciate by ticking the arrow and possibly upvoting.

Answer (score 2):

Use SparkSession instead of SQLContext. So do:

```
sqlContext = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").appName("appName").
                      config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "./spark-warehouse").getOrCreate()
```

The rest of your code should work normally.
You may adjust the variable name from `sqlContext` to reflect the reference held.

Comment: Ekaba answer worked for me. Just to add, The reason for the error is due to  .enableHiveSupport() present in shell.py file .

Comment: Okay. Great.
Please kindly update my answer with your observation. It will be helpful to others. And also, don't forget to leave an upvote :D

Comment: I have updated my observation here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42942620/spark-2-1-error-while-instantiating-hivesessionstate/45545595#45545595)

Comment: @EkabaBisong - You are my Hero!! I've been struggling to get a spark-submit work in a docker container for a couple hours, and this hivebuilder error was the last piece that needed fixing. Thank you!