# Unable to run scripts properly in AWS Glue PySpark Dev Endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

I've configured an AWS Glue dev endpoint and can connect to it successfully in a pyspark REPL shell - like this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/dev-endpoint-tutorial-repl.html

Unlike the example given in the AWS documentation I receive WARNings when I begin the session, and later on various operations on AWS Glue DynamicFrame structures fail. Here's the full log on starting the session - note the errors about spark.yarn.jars and PyGlue.zip:

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Sep  1 2016, 22:14:00)
[GCC 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/share/aws/glue/etl/jars/glue-assembly.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/spark/jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.16.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
18/03/02 14:18:58 WARN Client: Neither spark.yarn.jars nor spark.yarn.archive is set, falling back to uploading libraries under SPARK_HOME.
18/03/02 14:19:03 WARN Client: Same path resource file:/usr/share/aws/glue/etl/python/PyGlue.zip added multiple times to distributed cache.
18/03/02 14:19:13 WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database global_temp, returning NoSuchObjectException
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.1.0
      /_/

Using Python version 2.7.12 (default, Sep  1 2016 22:14:00)
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
>>>
```

Many operations work as I expect but I also receive some unwelcome exceptions, for example I can load data from my Glue catalog inspect its structure and the data within, but I can't apply a Map to it, or convert it to a DF. Here's my full execution run log (apart from the longest error message). The first few commands and setup all work well, but the final two operations fail:

```
>>> import sys
>>> from awsglue.transforms import *
>>> from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
>>> from pyspark.context import SparkContext
>>> from awsglue.context import GlueContext
>>> from awsglue.job import Job
>>>
>>> glueContext = GlueContext(spark)
>>> # Receives a string of the format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss.nnn and returns the first 10 characters: yyyy-mm-dd
... def TruncateTimestampString(ts):
...   ts = ts[:10]
...   return ts
...
>>> TruncateTimestampString('2017-03-05 06:12:08.376')
'2017-03-05'
>>>
>>> # Given a record with a timestamp property returns a record with a new property, day, containing just the date portion of the timestamp string, expected to be yyyy-mm-dd.
... def TruncateTimestamp(rec):
...   rec[day] = TruncateTimestampString(rec[timestamp])
...   return rec
...
>>> # Get the history datasource - WORKS WELL BUT LOGS log4j2 ERROR
>>> datasource_history_1 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "dev", table_name = "history", transformation_ctx = "datasource_history_1")
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
>>> # Tidy the history datasource - WORKS WELL
>>> history_tidied = datasource_history_1.drop_fields(['etag', 'jobmaxid', 'jobminid', 'filename']).rename_field('id', 'history_id')
>>> history_tidied.printSchema()
root
|-- jobid: string
|-- spiderid: long
|-- timestamp: string
|-- history_id: long

>>> # Trivial observation of the SparkSession objects
>>> SparkSession
<class 'pyspark.sql.session.SparkSession'>
>>> spark
<pyspark.sql.session.SparkSession object at 0x7f8668f3b650>
>>> 
>>> 
>>> # Apply a mapping to the tidied history datasource. FAILS
>>> history_mapped = history_tidied.map(TruncateTimestamp)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/mnt/tmp/spark-1f0341db-5de6-4008-974f-a1d194524a86/userFiles-6a67bdee-7c44-46d6-a0dc-9daa7177e7e2/PyGlue.zip/awsglue/dynamicframe.py", line 101, in map
File "/mnt/tmp/spark-1f0341db-5de6-4008-974f-a1d194524a86/userFiles-6a67bdee-7c44-46d6-a0dc-9daa7177e7e2/PyGlue.zip/awsglue/dynamicframe.py", line 105, in mapPartitionsWithIndex
File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2419, in __init__
    self._jrdd_deserializer = self.ctx.serializer
AttributeError: 'SparkSession' object has no attribute 'serializer'
>>> history_tidied.toDF()
ERROR
Huge error log and stack trace follows, longer than my console can remember. Here's how it finishes:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/mnt/tmp/spark-1f0341db-5de6-4008-974f-a1d194524a86/userFiles-6a67bdee-7c44-46d6-a0dc-9daa7177e7e2/PyGlue.zip/awsglue/dynamicframe.py", line 128, in toDF
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 79, in deco
    raise IllegalArgumentException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: u"Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState':"
```

I think I'm following the instructions given by Amazon in their Dev Endpoint REPL instructions, but with these fairly simple operations (DynamicFrame.join and DynamicFrame.toDF) failing I'm working in the dark when I want to run the job for real (which seems to succeed, but my DynamicFrame.printSchema() and DynamicFrame.show() commands don't show up in the CloudWatch logs for the execution).

Does anyone know what do I need to do to fix my REPL environment so that I can properly test pyspark AWS Glue scripts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AWS Support finally responded to my query on this issue. Here's the response:

> On researching further, I found that this is a known issue with the PySpark shell and glue service team is already on it. The fix should be deployed soon, however currently there's no ETA that I can share with you.
>
> Meanwhile here's a workaround: before initializing Glue context, you can do
>
> ```
> >> newconf = sc._conf.set("spark.sql.catalogImplementation", "in-memory")
> >> sc.stop()
> >> sc = sc.getOrCreate(newconf)
> ```
>
> and then instantiate glueContext from that sc.

I can confirm this works for me, here's a script I was able to run:

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

# New recommendation from AWS Support 2018-03-22
newconf = sc._conf.set("spark.sql.catalogImplementation", "in-memory")
sc.stop()
sc = sc.getOrCreate(newconf)
# End AWS Support Workaround

glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)

datasource_history_1 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "dev", table_name = "history", transformation_ctx = "datasource_history_1")

def DoNothingMap(rec):
  return rec

history_mapped = datasource_history_1.map(DoNothingMap)
history_df = history_mapped.toDF()
history_df.show()
history_df.printSchema()
```

Previously the `.map()` and `.toDF()` calls would fail.

I've asked AWS Support to notify me when this issue has been resolved so that the workaround is no longer required.

Comment: any thoughts on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49962306/aws-glue-error-not-able-to-read-glue-tables-from-developer-end-points-using-sp

Comment: It looks like this is related to this spark bug https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-26794 . It looks to be fixed in this patch that is only going to be included in the Spark 3.0.0 release (still release candidate) and likely a very long time before AWS Glue supports that version, see https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/23709 and the patch https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/ac9c0536bc518f173f2ff53bee42b7a89d28ee20

The GlueContext automatically supports integration with the Glue Catalog "external Hive catalog" as opposed to the in-memory Derby DB, so this workaround is bizarre

Comment: In your script you are referring to that SparkContext `sc` before it is declared, which is possible because it's a global created by the spark shell using your spark config, I'm wondering does your config specify `hive` as the `spark.sql.catalogImplementation` ?

Comment: I am having a similar issue where the code works in deployed site but not locally. However the AWS workaround does not work for me. Did AWS fix the issue from their end?

Answer (score 0):

Is the development endpoint configured on Windows or an Unix environment, looks like the downloaded files are not copied in the right location of linux, or code snippet is unable to find the path for the jars.  Please ensure the files are there.

I have setup a Zeppelin notebook on my windows machine, and am able to connect to glue catalog successfully.  Maybe you can try that as well, let me know if you need any help.

Comment: Thanks Yuva. I'm able to connect just fine, can you check in your Zeppelin notebook are you able to run any of the operations that cause me issues: DynamicFrame.toDF(), or DynamicFrame.map(someMapFunction)?

Comment: Not sure Yuva how Windows vs Unix impacts on the Dev Endpoint? OS isn't specified here: https://eu-west-1.console.aws.amazon.com/glue/home#addEditDevEndpoint: - I just SSH into the instance that Amazon sets up for me. All the code execution etc happens in that instance in the REPL shell. I'm going to try to setup Zeppelin myself to try this out and see what I come up with.

Comment: Can you please refer to this SO response: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42942620/spark-2-1-error-while-instantiating-hivesessionstate.  I think the suggestions/solutions provided there should work for you as well.

Comment: For zeppelin setup on windows laptop, this link (https://hernandezpaul.wordpress.com/2016/11/14/apache-zeppelin-installation-on-windows-10/) should help you.

Comment: Sorry Yuva Kumar, I can't accept the answer. I don't know if it's a solution or not. I can connect just fine to my AWS Glue Endpoint, I just find that I can't run some commands against it. You mention installation paths and Windows vs Unix, but the dev endpoint is automatically created by Amazon. I looked into setting up Zeppelin but that's a big effort and is beyond me - I just want to be able to run all Python commands from Amazon's examples and documentation directly against the Dev endpoint.

Comment: Specifically I can't run Map operations against a Glue DynamicFrame, or call toDF() on it. I don't see anything to suggest that this would improve if I go to the effort of installing Zeppelin.