# AWS Glue Error | Not able to read Glue tables from Developer End points using spark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I am not able to access AWS Glue tables even if I given all required IAM permissions. I cant even list all the databases.Here is the code.

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

# New recommendation from AWS Support 2018-03-22
newconf = sc._conf.set("spark.sql.catalogImplementation", "in-memory")
sc.stop()
sc = sc.getOrCreate(newconf)
# End AWS Support Workaround

glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
```

The error is here.while accessing one of the Glue table.

```
datasource_history_1 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "dev", table_name = "history", transformation_ctx = "datasource_history_1")
```

I tried to list databases also where I can see only the default one, nothing else(which I have created in Glue)

I tried to refer the below link, still did not help me.

[Unable to run scripts properly in AWS Glue PySpark Dev Endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49071424/unable-to-run-scripts-properly-in-aws-glue-pyspark-dev-endpoint/49958382#49958382)

Comment: This is an error that I am not able to gauge, are we not supposed to put out errors also ? Also, do we have some standard documentation which says we are not suppose to put our erros (if they are exceptions)

Comment: Please read the explanation. Errors are of course very useful (but if you work with PySpark don't cut off Java traceback, this is where useful things happen most of the time), but images are not (there are hard to read, depending on a device, and cannot be searched for). Please post the text version.

Comment: `newconf = sc._conf.set("spark.sql.catalogImplementation", "in-memory")` If you want to use the Glue Catalog (a Hive metastore) then using an in-memory catalog is going to cut off that ability. An in-memory catalog will let you register dataframe as tables and temp tables and run sparksql on them but these will not be in your Glue catalog. What was the exact recommendation from AWS Support?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have taken your code straight from this question braj: [Unable to run scripts properly in AWS Glue PySpark Dev Endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49071424) - but that code is specific to my Amazon Glue environment and the tables I'm referencing won't exist in your environment.

For this command to work:

```
datasource_history_1 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "dev", table_name = "history", transformation_ctx = "datasource_history_1")
```

Check your own Glue Catalog https://eu-west-1.console.aws.amazon.com/glue/home and ensure you have a table called history inside a database called dev. If you don't then I'm not sure what behaviour you expect to see from this code.

Instead of starting from a script taken from someone else's StackOverflow answer I suggest you create a Job in Glue and get it to generate the source connection code for you first. Use that as your starting point. It'll generate the create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog command for you in that script.

Comment: hey, no. Ofcourse I have used my table and schema and cant share due to security reasons. I will replace the image with actual errors.